# How to permanently change $PATH in docker container

Tags: docker, debian

I am building a docker image and want to permanently change its env vars and path. My simplified dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-slim-stretch

USER root

RUN pip3 install pyspark

RUN touch /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh && \
    echo export SPARK_HOME='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark' >> /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh && \
    echo export PATH='${SPARK_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' >> /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh && \
    echo export PYSPARK_PYTHON='python3.6' >> /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh && \
    chmod +x /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh
```

The image can be built successfully with `docker build -t data-job-base .`
But when I run it `docker run --rm -it data-job-base bash`, in this running container SPARK_HOME is empty and PATH has no change. I `cat /etc/profile.d/set-up-env.sh` and can see that it is properly written:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark
export PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6
```

I don't understand, why this set-up-env.sh doesn't get run when I start the shell?

Note that modifying `/etc/environment` has no effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved this by adding my shell commands in bash.bashrc instead of profile, profile.d, or environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ENV directive in the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8-slim-stretch
USER root
ENV SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark \
    PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/bin:${PATH} \
    PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6
RUN pip3 install pyspark
```